# Interactive Data Visualizations for the Web

Tags: d3.js

So I read the first eight chapters of the book Interactive Data Visualizations for the Web that was on the authors website. But still I need much more to learn specifically to learn how to get data at run time and how to update charts when I click on them, etc.. and they are in other chapters of the book.

But in the weblog it says here is a free "preview" :

http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449339739/

and then on the GiuHub I also found the source codes for the next chapters https://github.com/alignedleft/d3-book/tree/master/chapter_09

So do I still need to buy that book? I am worried if the content that is avaiable online is really just a "preview" but it doesn't look like it..

Has anyone tried that resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book is pretty similar to the OFPS. I bought the book to have it available offline (in the iPad) and to support the author and the community. I think that you can do just fine with the OFPS, but if you were to buy a D3 book, buy this one.